# increase textsize on button press flutter

Tags: flutter, textstyle

I am new to flutter and i am trying a simple function ..
i have a page with a text and a raised button i want to increase the text size by 1.0 each time the button is pressed ..
i have tried this but it is not working ..

```
class _StoryDetailsState extends State<StoryDetails> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var textSize = 10.0;

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xffEA3A82),
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    backgroundColor: Color(0xffEA3A82),
    title: Text(widget.story_title),
  )
  ,body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft
          ,child: Image.network(widget.story_detail_pic , width: double.infinity,)
      ),

      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('enlarge text'),
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            textSize = textSize + 1.0;
            print(textSize); 
          });
        },
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
            ,child: Container(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6) ,child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(widget.story , style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),),
            ))),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
);
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring `textsize` inside of build method. Every time set state is called the build method is called and your `textsize` is set to 10 again. Just move `var textSize = 10.0;` outside of build method and it will work fine.

```
class _StoryDetailsState extends State<StoryDetails> {
  var textSize = 10.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffEA3A82),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffEA3A82),
        title: Text("Title"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Image.network(
                  "http://via.placeholder.com/640x360",
                  width: double.infinity,
                )),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('enlarge text'),
              onPressed: () {
                textSize = textSize + 1.0;
                print(textSize);
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "story",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),
                        ),
                      ))),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```